# Security Crypto in android

Tags: android

I trying to use security crypto library to encrypt files. But the thing is I am using DocumentFile not File. But, in the library builder File is required.

I also tried using

```
val file = File(docFile.uri.path)
```

But it didn't work as well.

Could you tell me how to encrypt files using both DocumentFile and Crypto Library?

Comment: Does the `DocumentFile` have the absolute path property or function returning it?

Comment: No. You cannot get path in document file